# Лоби, лобио, фасоль

Tags: лексика, семантика

Недавно в разговоре с одной девушкой был очень удивлен, что ей незнакомы слова: лобио, лоби.

Хотелось бы узнать, а вы употребляете эти слова в своей речи, или же вы пользуетесь словом  фасоль.

До сегодняшнего дня я думал, что это разные названия одного и того же растения. Пока не заглянул в словарь. Оказывается, лоби(о) - это названия блюда из фасоли со специями у народов Кавказа.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Впервые слово "лобио" я услышала от дальней армянской родни, навещавшей армянскую же бабушку (дело происходило в центре Москвы). На вопрос: "А что это?" - получала: "Специально приготовленная фасоль".

Никогда не "лоби".

Слово может быть и не знакомо тому, кто не готовит и не пробовал сие блюдо.

Для меня - спецфасоль; не готовлю. Это сейчас "зёрна граната" на каждом шагу, а в советские времена желающие готовить лобио отоваривались на колхозных рынках, гурманы. Не у каждого ж рынок под боком...

[Вики пишет:](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BE)

> Лобио (от груз. ლობიო, [Лобио]) — грузинское блюдо, а также общее
> название для фасоли (как зелёной, стручковой, так и в зёрнах).
>
> Блюдо из лобио популярно у закавказских народов, как из стручков
> зелёной фасоли, а также из отварной красной фасоли с зеленью и/или
> зёрнами граната. Подаётся, как правило, с грузинским хлебом «Тонис
> пури» или «Шотис пури», испечённом на дровах.

В общем, чтобы знать слово "лобио", нужно или очень любить есть (а не все любят, для меня, например, процесс поглощения пиши - тяжкая работа, отбыть бы урок поскорее - и в "Инди Кота" нырнуть), или очень любить самостоятельно ставить гастрономические эксперименты.

Comment: Да, получается, у вас фасоль не очень популярна. Никогда не подумал бы.

Comment: Фасоль по-армянски  -лоби. В русской же культуре - лоби название кавказского блюда из фасоли. Так как я из Армении, всегда называл и блюдо и растение словом "лоби". Вот и произошла подмена понятий.